# Highcharts -how to change world regions style in area stacked charts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to this chart:
[image]

How can I style the world regions so that all of them appear? In the pre view they appear in a straight line but the final view they show in the columns of 3. Not all of them appear. TIA!

```css
//Grafica 1
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1350', '1400', '1450', '1500', '1550', '1699', '1750'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
            split: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff'
                }
            }
        },
           series: [{
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'L. America',
            data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'S-E. Asia',
            data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Japan',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'China',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Near East',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Asian CIS',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Russia',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'East Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Central Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'W. Europe - Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'N. America',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Would be really good to see what code you are using. How can we answer the question without it?

Comment: Yes sorry, please find code above. The regions appear in a line and I want to be able to put them in columns. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you are stacking to percentage and some of these data points are different by 2 orders of magnitude. I am not sure what you would expect to see? If you still want the tooltip to show all counties then set: `shared: true, split: false`.

Comment: Ok Thank you! yes indeed the differences are not big.